# capitalizing the date in wordpress (M d Y)

Tags: php, wordpress

I have this code in my theme.

```
$vandaag = the_date('M d. Y');
echo ucfirst($vandaag);
```

The output is still "okt 11. 2012"
I have the settings for wordpress in dutch, where apparently it doesn't capitalize the month. Any ideas why this doesn't work and still echos a lowercase month?

EDIT: I am using an English installation of wordpress, but have a plugin installed that changes the name of the month to dutch. This only works for the_date() and not when I use get_the_date(). This is what limited me to using the_date().

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
$vandaag = the_date('M d. Y', '', '', FALSE);
echo ucfirst($vandaag);
```

- https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/the_date

It will otherwise echo the value, setting the 4th argument to false will return instead.

Both get_the_date() and the_date() are correct depending on what you are wanting to do. Your preference really. Check out the documentation for both to decide what better fits your current usage.

Comment: Thank you, This works. I can't use get_the_date() because I'm using a plugin that changes the month to dutch but for some reason only does so when using the_date().

Answer (score 2):

Because you have to use [`get_the_date()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_the_date).

Answer (score 0):

In case the month (or whatever you need capitalized) is not at the start of your datestring use this:

```php
$date_string = ucwords(get_the_date('d F Y'));
echo $date_string;

// output -> 28 November 2022
```